# Unopened refrigerated Feta cheese over a year old

Tags: feta

I wanted to find out if the feta, discussed in a prior question from 2015, that was almost a year old was eaten without any gastric issues. I too have unopened feta that smells, tastes, and looks fine. I wanted to know if the person who posted ate the feta without being sick?

Comment: A link to the question is kind of essential here...assuming this is it? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59764/can-crumbled-feta-cheese-last-almost-a-year/59861#59861

Comment: Yes that is the question I was referring to.

Comment: If you have the same question as a previous one, the answers there are what we have. You can star it to be notified of any new answers. (And... knowing whether the OP there got sick doesn't really tell you whether it was safe, it's just one example. A lot of people drive without a seatbelt but that doesn't make it safe either.)